# My SFML/C++ program is working as expected but how to make movement slow?

Tags: c++, time, clock, sfml, gravity

I made a circle as our player and setted gravity but it is working so much faster and I can't even see. I think it has to do something with sf::time or sf::clock but how? I didn't actually got these two so any code example and explanation would be appreciated. Here is my code:-

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(20);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    shape.setPosition(380, 550);
    shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Green);
    shape.setOutlineThickness(3);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
                {
                    shape.move(0, -100);
                }
                if(event.KeyReleased)
                {
                    if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
                    {
                    int x[] = { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
                    for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++)
                    {
                        shape.move(0, x[y]);
                    }

                    }
                }

        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: s = v * t; your lacking any notion of time, thus the computer is moving the objects as fast as he can. You have to measure the time each iteration takes and then multiply that (delta) time with your speed.

Comment: @Paranaix is correct. You're computer is checking for the Up key press as fast as it can. Thus, you need to implement some sort of frame rate. I'm not too familiar with timing in SFML but depending on the precision of the clock, you can do something like if(clock() % 120) == 0) do keypress check. This makes it so you only do the check every 120 units of time (usually ms I think?)

Answer (score 8):

Remember you program is probably running hundreds of frames per second so when you press the up button on your keyboard it is moving the object -100 pixels per frame which is definitely not what you wanted.

So how do you fix this? You need to include the notion of time. We do this by using a time step to see how much time has past since the last frame was called.

Here is a short example code which shows how this time step could be structured (There are many different ways each with it's pros and cons).

```
sf::Time timePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.0f / 60.0f); // 60 frames per second
sf::Clock deltaClock;  // This will track how much time has past since the last frame
sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;

while (m_Window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Time deltaTime = deltaClock.restart();  // Restart returns the time since the last restart call
    timeSinceLastUpdate += deltaTime;

    while (timeSinceLastUpdate >= timePerFrame)
    {
        timeSinceLastUpdate -= timePerFrame;

        ProcessInput();
        Update(timePerFrame);  // Notice how I pass the time per frame to the update function
    }

    Render();
}
```

Then in your update code you just multiply the distance you want to move by the object timePerFrame that you passed into the update function (Make sure to use `sf::Time::asSeconds()`). For example your code would look like this

`shape.move(0, -100 * timePerFrame.asSeconds());`

If you are looking for a in depth explanation on how time steps work I would recommend this article http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Answer (score 1):

As @Zereo responsed but with a simplied version: instead of you taking care of framerates you can let the SFML take care:

```
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
```

Put this line after creating of window and SFML will limit your frames at 60/s.

Comment: There is a potential problem with this, in that 60fps is just an upper limit. So, for example, if the application could only reach 30fps, the action would slow to half-speed.

Comment: As Kaathe said using window.SetFramerateLimit(60); gives you very little control and the implementation unless they have changed it recently uses sf::Sleep which is notorious for being inaccurate https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-setframeratelimit-always-set-the-frame-rate-to-the-specified-limit. So I would highly recommend against using it. Also would like to add that even if you did use that it wouldn't fix the problem at hand since it provides you no way to get how much time has past since the last frame.

Comment: So it's not good at all to limit the frames? Even if is a small project?

Comment: If by limiting the frames you mean using window.setFramerateLimit() then correct I wouldn't recommend using it specially since it is fairly easy to set up your own and have much more control over it. For little toy projects I guess it would be fine though make sure you remember to get the time that has past since the last frame still. But for anything even remotely serious you definitely wouldn't want to use it for the reasons already stated.